# Visual studio debugger not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, remote-debugging

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio debugger to debug a remote application. These are the steps I have done

1. I have taken the x86 version of the msvsmon.exe in the remote machine (which has 32 bit OS) where the application to be debuggedis running. I have started the exe with the options No authentication and Allow any user to debug.
2. In Visual studio I set Debug option as Win32, go to Tools and Attach the process. I give the IP, choose the transport type as remote and try to start the debugger. However, I am getting the following error message  --
   Unable to connect to ‘MyMachine’. The Microsoft Visual studio Remote debugging monitor is either not running on the remote machine or is running in windows authentication mode.

I have checked the firewall settings. Please help if you have any idea as to what could be the issue.

Comment: You said you specified the IP address, but did you also specify the port? E.g.: `192.168.X.X:4015`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are debugging native code then run the remote debugger in no-authentication mode. MSDN has notes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164723.aspx). Note that you have to connect to the remote debugger quickly (within 30 seconds) in this mode, otherwise it times-out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify "Native debugging" in Attach to process dialog?

Comment: Yes I did , this is the option that comes -Remote (native only with no authentication)

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is firewall settings. Since you previously checked that, I'm out of suggestions.